# Turning loop of string inputs from Excel into Python lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file with three columns (Prefix, Feature, Values).  All three are strings in Excel, but I need to turn the 'Values' entry from a string into a list when Prefix and Column equal the loop values.

Data looks like this:

| Prefix | Feature | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prefix_1 | Feature1 | Value1,Value2,Value3 |
| Prefix_1 | Feature2 | Value4,Value5 |
| Prefix_1 | Feature3 | Value6,Value7,Value8,Value9 |
| Prefix_2 | Feature4 | Value10 |

It loops through all prefixes, then through all features, and I want to return the values in a list.

```
parametric_values = str(filtered_input.loc[filtered_input.Feature==column,'Value']).split(',')
```

`filtered_input` is a dataframe that is filtered to only the relevant prefixes and column is the value from the loop.

I would have expected parametric_values to be `['Value1','Value2','Value3']` for the first loop, but it returned as `['0    Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3\nName: Value', ' dtype: object']`

I'm not sure why it returned a 0 to start with or the name and dtype object. What would I need to change with my code to get it to just return the values in the list?

Comment: Don't convert the result into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
filtered_input.loc[filtered_input.Feature==column,'Value'].str.split(',').squeeze()
```

Comment: Why does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Alert**
From now on whenever you are trying to work with any pandas column values please avoid using the direct typecast ( bad practice ) and rather use `astype()` to change value type.

And Now For the solution to your problem please change your code as follows

```
parametric_values = filtered_input.loc[filtered_input.Feature==column,'Value'].astype(str).str.split(',').tolist()[0]
```

here,

```
filtered_input.loc[filtered_input.Feature==column,'Value'].astype(str).str.split(',')
```

This portion will only return a pandas series which is not the desired output so this series needs to be converted into a list. that's why `tolist()` is added. But when you make a pandas series a list that also contains a list within it. Which will eventually generate something like this.

> [['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']]

which is also undesired output so lastly that `[0]` is added to get the actual list that you need.
Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: "But when you make a pandas series a list..."

Is that why it returned the extra stuff in my output (e.g. dtype)?  Because it was actually a list of several things, and returning just the 0th item is the actual values that I want?

Either way, thanks for this.  It helped me understand the language better.